# Payara 5, Customize Restful json bean properties

Tags: java, jsonb, payara, java-ee-8

I'm trying to change the name of a bean's attribute in a RESTFUL response.  I know Payara 5 uses Jsonb as default serialization library but seems that  @JsonbProperty annotation is ignored.
E.g. If the bean is:

```
public class MyBean implements java.io.Serializable {
    ....

   @JsonbProperty("myId")
    private Long id;

}
```

The returned json is { "id": 1234 }, instead of { "myId": 1234 }

Someone has encountered the same problem or I'm missing something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Adding the lib `jakarta.json.bin-api.jar` (located at the 'modules' folder) to the war containing the Web Service resolves the problem.